# Proof that the mapping of the surface area of an triangle is surjective

Tags: real-analysis

This is the problem:

$\mathbb{R^2}$ is the set of points in the plane and $F: \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^+_0}$ the mapping of the surface area of the triangle with corners $(0,1), (1,0)$ and $P$ to $P$. Is $F$ injective, surjective or bijective?

This was my idea so far:

Domain: $$ f: \mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^+_0}$$
$$F(x, y) = \frac{1}{2}*\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$ (Since the base of the triangle is 1 and the absolute value of $ \overrightarrow{p}$ is the height of the triangle).

Proofing that $F$ isn't injective was easy, but I'm stuck when it comes to proving that it's surjective (which I supposse that it is). How do you go about proofing this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=(1,0)$, $B=(0,1)$ and $P$ a generic point $(x,y)$.

►The equation of the line $L$ passing by $A$ and $B$ is $x+y-1=0$.

►The distance d(A,B)is equal to $\sqrt2$.

►The distance of $P$ to the line $L$ is equal to $\dfrac{|x+y-1|}{\sqrt2}$.

►The area of the triangle $\triangle ABP$ is equal to $\dfrac{\sqrt2|x+y-1|}{2\sqrt2}=\dfrac{|x+y-1|}{2}$

It follows for all $z\in\mathbb{R^+_0}$ there is a point $(x,y)$ such that $\dfrac{|x+y-1|}{2}=z$.

This is clear making $x+y=1+2 z$.

Thus $F$ is surjective.